# Raspberry Pi 5 shuts down while running code

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

Iam running a deep learning code consist of cnn model and yolov5 when I run the code in raspberry Pi 5 it shut down automatically can anyone Provide suggestions to carry on with it

Comment: What power supply? How much memory is being used?